# ConnectionWaitTimeoutException in IBM Websphere

Tags: annotations, timeout, websphere, database-connection, connection-pooling

The application we run on is based on Struts 2.0. Many of us access this application simultaneously. Every evening around the same time, the application comes to a haul. If we reload the application on the browser, it never moves ahead of the Login page. 
Seeing the logs for the server, I can see that the last message was "thread sleep".

On doing some research I came across the use of  annotation for Spring framework. Does the same work for Struts2 also?
Can u please illustrate the use if possible in a struts file?

```
[4/25/12 15:20:19:595 GMT+05:30] 00000029 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:19,595 DEBUG [Thread-64][GreeceSynchronizer] thread sleep
action [cape.base.lbxoutclearing.ui.action.LoginAction@1f601f6]
[4/25/12 15:20:26:293 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,293 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][I18nInterceptor] intercept '//doLogin' { 
[4/25/12 15:20:26:293 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,293 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][I18nInterceptor] requested_locale=null
[4/25/12 15:20:26:293 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,293 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][I18nInterceptor] before Locale=en_US
[4/25/12 15:20:26:293 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,293 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][InstantiatingNullHandler] Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[cape.base.lbxoutclearing.ui.action.LoginAction@1f601f6, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@58605860], property=struts]
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][FileUploadInterceptor] Bypassing // doLogin
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][StaticParametersInterceptor] Setting static parameters {}
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][ParametersInterceptor] Setting params password => [ DEMO9 ] changePassword => [ false ] forgotPassword => [  ] username => [ DEMO9 ] 
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][XWorkConverter] Property: changePassword
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][XWorkConverter] Class: cape.base.lbxoutclearing.ui.action.LoginAction
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][XWorkConverter] field-level type converter for property [changePassword] = none found
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][XWorkConverter] global-level type converter for property [changePassword] = none found
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][XWorkConverter] falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.XWorkBasicConverter@48c648c6]
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][CompoundRootAccessor] No object in the CompoundRoot has a publicly accessible property named 'forgotPassword' (no setter could be found).
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][CompoundRootAccessor] No object in the CompoundRoot has a publicly accessible property named 'password' (no setter could be found).
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][CompoundRootAccessor] No object in the CompoundRoot has a publicly accessible property named 'username' (no setter could be found).
[4/25/12 15:20:26:294 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,294 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][LoginAction] Validating login
[4/25/12 15:20:26:295 GMT+05:30] 00000030 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:26,295 DEBUG [WebContainer : 5][LoginAction] 1
[4/25/12 15:20:31:256 GMT+05:30] 00000036 FreePool      E   J2CA0045E: Connection not available while invoking method createOrWaitForConnection for resource lockBoxDSJNDI.
[4/25/12 15:20:31:292 GMT+05:30] 00000036 SystemOut     O 25 Apr 2012 15:20:31,289 ERROR [WebContainer : 8][BaseDAO] Exception in getConnection()
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 180007
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1252)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:444)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:400)
    at cape.base.lbxoutclearing.ui.dao.BaseDAO.getConnection(BaseDAO.java:49)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 180007
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1496)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2273)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:903)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:603)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:431)
    ... 130 more
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Struts/Spring.

The container WAS says it is unable to get a connection from the connection pool.

A Connectiontimeout period is specified on the data source. If after waiting for that period of time, if the WAS runtime is not able to provide your application with a connection from the pool, then it throws this exception.

You got to find out who is holding on to the connections in the pool and ensure that connections are released.

Turn on the trace with this tracestring ConnLeakLogic=finest. When this exception occurs, it would dump the state listing all threads that are using the connections at that point in time. This should be the starting point for you.

HTH

Manglu